# Select column for each row in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

All,

I have a numpy array with the shape (32, 2, ...)

I would like to select either the first or second column in axis 1 using an array of 32 0s and 1s. The final array should have shape (32, ...).

I've tried: `arr[:, select]`, but that comes up with the shape (32, 32, ...).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `a[np.arange(32),select]`:

```
a.shape, a[np.arange(32),select].shape
# ((32, 2, 4), (32, 4))
```

Comment: This is correct. Although I'm not sure why...